# How to call each element from an np.array?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function which returns 20 numbers.  [2,7,7,2,5,9,8,6,5,9,9,3,2,4,5,5,4,7,1,0]

These numbers represent a coordinate in the computer's screen. Ex:

0 = 510,382

1 = 640,382

...

8 = 770,642

Then I will display a circle with those coordinates on the screen.

So, how do I call each element from the array "pos"? But as an integer.

```
positions = np.array([[510,382], [510,512],[510,642], \
                              [640,382],[640,512],[640,642], \
                              [770,382],[770,512],[770,642]],)

pos = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,1])

for i in range (0, pos.shape[0]):
    posX = positions[pos][0]
    posY = positions[pos][1]

    print(posX, posY)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, but I do not know why it works.
And when I replaced "pos" for

```
self.generateSequence(20, 5)
```

I get this error: 'XX' object has no attribute 'pos'

Anyways, this is the answer:

```
for i in range (0, pos.shape[0]):
    posX = positions[pos[i]][0]
    posY = positions[pos[i]][1]

    print(posX, posY)
```